# End marker in quotes inside block comment

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to add a block comment where the start marker (/*) appears inside quotes:

```
/*
const val MIME_TYPE = "image/*"
*/
```

This is possible in Java, but fails in Kotlin. The same problem arises with the end marker inside the quotes. Is this a known compiler bug/limitation? Is there any alternative syntax (besides line comments) that allow me to maintain the string definition inside a block comment?

Comment: The title and question refer both to a start marker and an end marker inside the quotes; only the former is correct.  — I think the real issue here is that in Kotlin, unlike Java, comments _nest_: so after the two `/*`, you need two `*/` to end the comment.

Comment: Just use \ instead /

Comment: @gidds You are right that the behaviour is different for start marker and end marker, but both lead to problems. So if the start marker appears inside the comments, your solution with two end markers work. If the end marker appears inside the comments, I need to set two start markers.

Comment: You can submit a new issue to the Kotlin devs: [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT). Currently you can fix this by hand. Like @Vlad and @georkost already mentioned, with the escape character you can disable the commenting function. But instead of only escaping the forward slash `/` you have to escape the asterisk `*` too. Thats because in a block comment that character is expected to be the beginning of the end block. Finally your string would look like this: `"image\/\*"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```kotlin
/**
const val MIME_TYPE = "image\/*"
*/
```

### EDIT:

You have to use the escape character `\` because `/` is special character.

Comment: This still fails for me (Android Studio 4.1.1, Kotlin 1.4.20-release-Studio4.1-1).

Comment: I've found the issue it was the `/` on `image/*`. You have to escape it

Comment: It fails for me also with the escape character.